# How to check if a value exists in a Subquery which returns more than 1 row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to extract the information of the film where it's genre isn't 'Sci-Fi'. But I'm getting an error of `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row` and I just can't fix this issue. I'm using this query: `SELECT * FROM film WHERE id != (SELECT id FROM genre WHERE type='Sci-Fi');` to get the results. I think I have to fix the `id !=` area but I don't know the command to check if the current id of the film exists in the returned rows of id. Please Help me with this. Also I'm new to `SQL` so if my current database isn't good for this particular task, please comment below.

`IF THERE IS BETTER WAY TO STORE genres OF INDIVIDUAL FILMS, PLEASE LET ME KNOW.`

`TABLE (with rows): film:`

[image]

`TABLE (with rows): genre:`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write:

```
SELECT * FROM film WHERE id not in (SELECT id FROM genre WHERE type='Sci-Fi');
```

Answer (score 8):

I strongly recommend using `not exists` rather than `not in`.  There is a good reason.  If any value returned by the subquery is `NULL`, then `not in` filters out *all* rows.  This behavior is consistent with the meaning of `NULL`, but it is highly counter-intuitive.

So I would recommend:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM film f
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM genre g
                  WHERE g.id = f.id
                 );
```

You also ask about your data structure.  You should have three tables:

- `films`, one row per film with a `filmId` column
- `genres`, one row per genre (such as "sci-fi") with a `genreId` column.
- `filmGenres`, one row per genre per film (with `filmId` and `genreId` columns).

The third table is called a junction or association table.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the result you want using a `LEFT JOIN` against films that have a genre of `Sci-Fi` and checking that there is no match between the tables:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM film f
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM genre WHERE type = 'Sci-Fi') g
  ON g.id = f.id
WHERE g.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Numerous rows return though.

Comment: @Aman I hadn't noticed your genre table had multiple genres for each film. The modified query will work now.